# How to bind a single string variable or array to mysqli insert statement

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, prepared-statement

Here's my insert statement that I'm trying to run

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO styles1 ($names) VALUES ($placeholders)");
    $stmt->bind_param($dataTypes, $values);
    $stmt-execute();
```

but I'm getting a 'Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables' error, even though they do. I'm assuming the bind_param() expects 8 variables for 8 placeholders, but would be much more useful if I could just use one. Each variable is a string of data that is echoed out just like below:

```
$names = width, height, color, depth, posX, posY, rotate, corners
$values = 56, 35, green, 4, 52, 24, 345, 64
$placeholders = ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
$dataTypes = "ssssssss"
```

Would PDO be a better option?

Comment: Have you tried with green like 'green'

Comment: Yes, PDO is almost always a better option. But even in PDO you have to put as many placeholders as you have variables to bind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the splat ([...](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat)) operator to pass in an array of variables and PHP will expand them into individual values for the function call.

First make sure your array is defined correctly...

```
$values = [56, 35, "green", 4, 52, 24, 345, 64];
```

and then

```
$stmt->bind_param($dataTypes, ...$values);
```

Comment: Still having trouble with the splat operator on the $values. Even when I manually insert the column names, binding placeholders, and data types to test it out, it still doesn't go through. Think I need to find a new approach

Comment: It would help if you show what errors you get.  It may be something solvable, but without further info it would be just guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **call_user_func_array** and make the values into an array

```
$values = [56, 35, 'green', 4, 52, 24, 345, 64];
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $values);
$stmt->execute();
```

Hope this helps